# How can I adjoin images with ImageMagick for pixel art?

Tags: pixel

Joining 55x55 imageA and imageB 55x55 should result int a joined image 55x110 but imagemagick acts oddly.

> **Trial 1: adding some dummy pixels, bad**
>
> ```
> $ montage -adjoin sky_0_1.png sky_0_3.png sky_0_4.png
> $ identify sky_0_1.png sky_0_3.png sky_0_4.png 
> sky_0_1.png PNG 55x55 55x55+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 3.32KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> sky_0_3.png[1] PNG 55x55 55x55+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 5.68KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> sky_0_4.png[2] PNG 256x126 256x126+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 10.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> ```
>
> **Trial 2: trying to fix the dummy pixels with size -flag, not working**
>
> ```
> $ montage -size 55x55 -adjoin sky_0_1.png sky_0_3.png sky_0_4.png 
> $ identify sky_0_4.png 
> sky_0_4.png PNG 256x126 256x126+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 10.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000
> ```

I waited for sky_0_4.png to be of size 110x55, not 256x126 -- in pixel art, I need to have specific sizes. How can I do the join of images in imagemagick (notice that montage is its command)?

> **Helper questions**
>
> 1. Suppose I have different-sized images, how can I make the block of images to have the unit size by the largest picture (meaning every
>      block of the same size and each image centered or put to the top-left-corner)?
> 2. Suppose a game engine such as old [Crafty.js](http://craftyjs.com/) does not support flopping programmtically, I need flopped images. How can I get flopped
>      images to the sprites -image (not to have so much overhead)?

Comment: Not many designers use ImageMagick, it's more often used by programmers. You might get lucky here, but you're more likely to get a good answer to a question about using code libraries on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `montage -geometry +0+0 sky_0_1.png sky_0_3.png sky_0_4.png`. You'll find more at ImageMagick's [montage examples page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/)